# django time zone for printing date

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

I have django project with `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'` set in settings.py.

I am using dates like this:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

dateobject = parse_datetime(some_string)
now = datetime.now()
if now > dateobject:
    # do something
```

Then in template I use:

```
dateobject|date:"d M Y H:i"
```

All I want to display dates in ALL my templates in different time zone (for example +6 hours). But I want project timezone to be 'America/Chicago' and date returned by datetime.now() was in this timezone. So I just want to change all dates DISPLAYED to be +6 hours for example. How I can accomplish this?

---

edit

Okay this works for me:

```
{% load tz %}
{{ datetimevalue|timezone:"Europe/Paris" }}
```

It prints date with +1 hour. But this doesn't work:

```
{% load tz %}
{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
{{ datetimevalue }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

It prints date unchanged. I have to set it globally for all templates. How I can do it?

I always use date filter (`dateobject|date:"d M Y H:i"`) so maybe is there any way to "hook" this filter globally to change it to `dateobject|timezone:"Europe/Paris"|date:"d M Y H:i"` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is more a python question, you can use the `timedelta` variable to add time to a `datetime`. for example

```
import datetime
b = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=n)
```

Or you can directly change the timezone of the `datetime`, for example:

```
datetime.astimezone(GMT2())
```

Or with the `tzinfo` variable in the `now` functions:

```
datetime.datetime.now(EST())
```

So these changes have to be done before you pass something to your templates.

Comment: I have to set it globally for all my django project - I cant track every date function use and modify it...

Comment: Then, you should reconfigure your app, but you also can do it from the template with these features https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: I edited my question - your link helped me but not completely

Comment: You can use `template inheritance`. If this is helping, you should show appreciation. I am also looking that my answer was what you were looking for, but know you have *changed* what you want.

Comment: I wrote that timezone tags doesnt work - only timezone filter - so I cant include this in template inheritance...

Comment: I posted new question to be more precise what I am looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635446/pytz-timezone-tags-to-adjust-date-printed-in-templates

Answer (score 0):

See: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone.

```
{% now h:ia %}
```

Try this one ..........