# pytz timezone tags to adjust date printed in templates

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz

Inside my app I use normal datetime objects. In my template:

```
{% load tz %}

{{datetimeobject|timezone:"Europe/Paris"}}

{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
{{datetimeobject}}
{% endtimezone %}
```

This prints something like this:

```
Dec. 5, 2012, 4 p.m.
Dec. 5, 2012, 3 p.m.
```

So the timezone filter adjusts the date but timezone tag DOES NOT.

Why is that? And how I can use tag properly? My goal is to adjusts all datetimeobjects in whole template without adding filter to every datetimeobject printed in template.

---

edit

I tried to make my dateobjects timezone aware:

```
offset = timezone('Europe/London')
datetimeobj.replace(tzinfo=offset)
```

But that didnt help - still of the previous code but with tz aware datetimeobject is:

```
Dec. 5, 2012, 4 p.m.
Dec. 5, 2012, 3 p.m.
```

---

solved: I had a mistake in above code - should be:

```
offset = timezone('Europe/London')
datetimeobj = datetimeobj.replace(tzinfo=offset)
```

Comment: I notice you have `import tz` where the documentation has `load tz` is that intentional?

Comment: I my original code I have load, sory, I will edit this

Comment: `datetimeobj.replace(tzinfo=zone)` is incorrect, use `zone.localize(datetimeobj, is_dst=None)` instead (assuming `datetimeobj` is a naive datetime object) or `zone.normalize(datetimeobj.astimezone(zone))` (assuming timezone-aware datetime object). See http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: read [the link I provided](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to understand when, how, and why it breaks.

Comment: I recommend simply using the [timezone API of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/) and adapt the examples found there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you use "normal datetime objects", but apparently they are [timezone naive instead of timezone aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts).

The [timezone filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone) "forces conversion of a single value to an arbitrary timezone" while the [timezone tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone) just sets the current timezone until the `endtimezone` tag.

Your `datetimeobject` is timezone naive and the timezone filter will convert it to a timezone aware datetime with the default timezone and then represent it in the timezone given to the filter.

Comment: I tried to convert datwtimeobjects to be tz aware but that didnt help - see my edited post

Comment: Sorry my mistake it should be `datetimeobj = datetimeobj.replace(tzinfo=offset)` - it works now, thanks